# How can I prevent Knex from inserting trailing spaces on PostgreSQL?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, knex.js

I'm using `Node` and the packages `pg` and `Knex` to insert data on `PostgreSQL`. This is my source code:

```
var knex = require('knex')({
    client: 'pg',
    connection: 'postgres://postgres:52Ag98d5@localhost:5433/CRM'
});

var rows = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 20000; i++)
{
    rows.push({
        name: faker.Name.findName(),
        email: faker.Internet.email()
    });
}

knex.batchInsert('contact', rows)
    .then(() => {
        knex.destroy();
    });
```

It works great, except that the string fields are being filled with trailing spaces. I mean... If a field is `character(50)` and I fill it with 10 characters, it's going to insert 40 spaces at the end. See the highlight on `pgAdmin`:

[image]

I don't know whose fault this is. I don't know if this is because of `Knex` or because of the Node `pg` driver.

Any ideia how to prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reason is very simple. `Character(50)` is fixed-length datatype.

> [Character datatype](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-character.html):
>
> ```
> ╔════════════════════════╦════════════════════════════╗
> ║          Name          ║        Description         ║
> ╠════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════╣
> ║ character(n), char(n)  ║ fixed-length, blank padded ║
> ╚════════════════════════╩════════════════════════════╝
> ```
>
> **If the string to be stored is shorter than the declared length,
>   values of type character will be space-padded;** values of type
>   character varying will simply store the shorter string.

Solution:

Use `VARCHAR(50)` instead.

Comment: I'm feeling retarded.. But yes, I don't know much about PostgreSQL. Thank you stranger. I'm accepting in 2 minutes